# fisher test :how to get two files in one and perform a fisher test

Tags: r

I have two files(healthy vs cancer) containing transposable elements classes and subclasses(two columns) but one has 71602 row and the other 72500,I tried to put them as a data frame in one file to perform fisher test and see wether one classe  was more significant in cancer than in healthy tissu but havent managed to get it.
does anyone know how to get one file and perform a fisher test?

Answer (score 0):

The input for a Fisher test is a 2x2 contingency table. What you want to is read in your two files separately, then generate a contingency table from them. You do not need to combine your two files into one data frame. For example, you can do

```
df1<-data.frame(health=rep("healthy", 5), TE=sample(c("A", "B"), 5, replace=T))


df2<-data.frame(health=rep("cancer", 7), TE=sample(c("A", "B"), 7, replace=T))


ctable<-matrix(c(sum(df1$TE=='A'), sum(df1$TE=='B'), sum(df2$TE=='A'), sum(df2$TE=='B')), nrow=2, ncol=2, dimnames=list(c("A", "B"), c("Healthy", "Cancer")))

ctable

fisher.test(ctable)
```